Difficulty locating Birth GRO for Mary Coke (towards end of 1852 or early 1853)
I am stumped as to why I can't find a birth GRO reference for Mary Coke. She had several siblings and I am aware that birth records began in 1837.
Before Records Began

John 1829 (baptised 10.09.1828)
James 1833 (baptised 24.03.1833)
Ann 1836 (baptised 04.10.1835)

After Records Began

Humphrey 1841 GRO Shaftesbury Jan 1841 8 85 (surname Coake)
Maria 1847 (baptised 22.10.1847) GRO Shaftesbury Dec 1847 8 75
Sarah 1850 (baptised 21.07.1850) GRO Shaftesbury Sep 1850 8 83
Mary 1853 (baptised 16.01.1853 Enmore Green - Dorset)
Emily 1855 (baptised 20.06.1855) GRO Shaftesbury Jun 1855 5a 230
Martha 1858 (baptised 23.05.1838) GRO Shaftesbury Jun 1858 5a 231 (my Great Great Grandmother)
Elizabeth 1860 (baptised 25.03.1860) GRO Jun 1860 Shaftesbury 5a 231
Wyndham 1866 (baptised 12.05.1866) GRO Jun 1866 Shaftesbury 5a 231

I have struggled to find a Baptism or GRO for Humphrey and the GRO for Mary Coke is nowhere to be found. Thoughts?
Update
Found Humphrey’s birth GRO. Was under Coake and not Coke.

Looking at the 1853 baptismal record for Mary Coke on FamilySearch, I'm wondering whether you have searched for Cote and Cole because the K is really questionable. Also on FreeBMD you can do a phonetic search to pick up Coake/Koch.

@shoover I did stumble upon Mary Cole too and wondered if that might be hers. But when looking at the source image it is clear they are all Cole so it isn’t a transcription error.  I’ve used FreeBMD a lot but not the phonetic search.

Have you searched for alternative names for Mary and Humphrey? I have found that sometimes first names are miss transcribed in the index and also the first name that you are searching on is not their actual first name but is sometimes their middle name or just the name they were known by later in life.
Have you searched the GRO index for just the surname with the RD of Shaftesbury as that can be useful? There is for instance an Edith Cole with a Q1 birth and mothers maiden name of Marsh.

Hi Colin. I have attempted to do so on both the GRO site and FreeBMD. In this case the mothers maiden surname is Kendal.

Actually, the first 4 were from his first wife who had the surname Maidment. She passed away.
